# pyarmor exe file is treated as a virus threat by windows defender

Tags: python, python-3.x, virus, virus-scanning, pyarmor

I use below command to create a single exe file

```
pyarmor pack -e " --onefile" final.py
```

and it works perfectly until windows defender starts to scan for viruses and define this exe file as virus!

Comment: why is `--onefile` in quotes?  Just make an exception in windows defender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved by adding --clean

```
pyarmor pack --clean -e "--onefile " final.py
```